# Using stdin in a mutually exclusive argument group

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to use `argparse` in a script such that I could pass a string either as an argument or via standard input. I figured I could use [`add_mutually_exclusive_group`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) for that, and set `required=True` to enforce that just one argument is required. So, I created the following script (`my_script.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
from sys import stdin

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('str_arg', nargs='?', type=str)
group.add_argument('str_in', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=stdin)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.str_arg or args.str_in.readline()
```

Passing the string as a parameter works fine. However, when I try to pipe the string from standard input like so:

```
$ echo Hello | python my_script.py
```

Python complains that `one of the arguments str_arg str_in is required`. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you want a user to be able to pass a filename as `str_in` and then read that file? If not, then that indicates `FileType` is not a good choice.

Comment: Correct, passing the filename is not required.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Do you want to give the user the option of passing an argument to `str_in` that doesn't represent stdin?

Comment: That's what I said -- it's not a requirement. So, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you should try doing this with fancy argparse features, just some simple logic:

```
import argparse
from sys import stdin

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('str_arg', nargs='?', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.str_arg or stdin.readline())
```

Comment: This would block if nothing is coming in to through stdin, correct?

Comment: @bigT It will block until it receives a newline or end of input from stdin. If you run `python my_script.py` at a terminal and don't pipe anything in, then stdin comes directly from the terminal and it will wait until you press Enter or Ctrl+D.

Comment: I think in terms of functionality, this serves the purpose well. The only drawback I see here is the blocking part if nothing was passed to the script, in which case the script should say something rather than waiting for input. Perhaps calling `sys.stdin.isatty()` would suffice?

Comment: @bigT maybe, I'm not an expert on stdin. Why not just always print 'reading from stdin'?

Comment: I suppose I could do that, or maybe something like:

    `if not str_arg:`
        `if stdin.isatty():`
            `parser.print_usage()`
            `raise ValueError('"str_arg" is required and must be passed as either an argument or via STDIN')`

Comment: @bigT rather use `parser.error`, they don't need to see a traceback.

Comment: Would you be okay if I made an edit to your answer to reflect what we talked about here?

Comment: @bigT I don't think that's a good idea because what we've discussed here is not really related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

2 positionals in a mutually exclusive group does not work.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('str_arg', nargs='?')
group.add_argument('str_in', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

sample runs:

```
0217:~/mypy$ python3 stack49705916.py 
usage: stack49705916.py [-h] (str_arg | str_in)
stack49705916.py: error: one of the arguments str_arg str_in is required

0904:~/mypy$ python3 stack49705916.py foo
Namespace(str_arg='foo', str_in=None)

0904:~/mypy$ python3 stack49705916.py foo bar
usage: stack49705916.py [-h] (str_arg | str_in)
stack49705916.py: error: argument str_in: not allowed with argument str_arg
```

piping is not a substitute for a commandline argument.  `stdin` has to be read separately.

```
import argparse, sys
print(sys.argv)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('str_arg', nargs='?')
group.add_argument('str_in', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
print(sys.stdin.read())

0909:~/mypy$ echo 'hello' | python3 stack49705916.py foo
['stack49705916.py', 'foo']
Namespace(str_arg='foo', str_in=None)
hello
```

`argparse.FileType('r')` recognizes `-` as `stdin`.

```
print(sys.argv)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--str_in', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
print(args.str_in.read())
```

runs

```
0945:~/mypy$ python3 stack49705916.py -i test.txt
['stack49705916.py', '-i', 'test.txt']
Namespace(str_in=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
2000+0
2001+2
2002+1

0946:~/mypy$ python3 stack49705916.py -i -
['stack49705916.py', '-i', '-']
Namespace(str_in=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
typing hello on input line

typing hello on input line


0947:~/mypy$ echo Hello | python3 stack49705916.py -i -
['stack49705916.py', '-i', '-']
Namespace(str_in=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
Hello

0947:~/mypy$
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. It does seem that I would have to read stdin separately. However, the only thing I would need to handle is to prevent the script from blocking (unnecessarily) if no input was given via the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

In a shell you can pass the output of `echo Whatever` as an argument using back quotes and not a pipe:

```
$ python my_script.py `echo whatever`
```

Comment: Sure, but this does not address my question.